# Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 on Sony VAIO computers with UEFI?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, uefi, vaio

I have a Sony VAIO SVF14213CLB laptop, with a Core i3 64-bit processor. This computer has UEFI security, and I want to install Ubuntu 14.04. I want to know if the hardware is compatible with Ubuntu.

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit, but when I configure motherboard to legacy in order to boot from the Live CD, it doesn't work. It reads the disc, but when there is an Ubuntu message it seems that it's loading, but it's not, and the Ubuntu message still there...

Maybe this could be because my computer is 64-bit, and that's why I'm downloading the Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit version. But I want to know if it is compatible with this computer...

Comment: I tried install ubuntu 14.04 with UEFI mode and using USB stick flash drive, it's installed well but after request reboot to complete installation it doesn't boot in UEFI mode and it's not working for me!!!

Comment: @KasiyA Maybe you forgot to set it back to boot from the hard drive in the BIOS?

Comment: In general, a 64-bit computer should be able to run a 32-bit operating system, so that can't be the issue here.

Comment: Ok, i've tried to boot the 64-bit live cd and it Works perfectly, thanks... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to install a 32-bit version of Ubuntu on a computer with a 64-bit UEFI. (The vast majority of 64-bit UEFI-based PCs have 64-bit UEFIs.) At best, you'll end up with Ubuntu installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, whereas Windows will be in EFI/UEFI mode. This is awkward to manage and can be limiting.

Instead, use a 64-bit version of Ubuntu and install it *in EFI mode!* Note that many Web sites give poor instructions that involve switching the computer to BIOS mode to do the installation, followed by repairing the damage done by this poor decision late in the process. See [my Web page on EFI-mode installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) or [the Ubuntu community wiki on the subject](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) for better advice and procedures.