# Install Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a Sony Vaio SVS13A1S9ES. I installed Windows 8.1 in my computer and now I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I've installed grub in sda6, which is my "/" partition. The problem is that when I boot, I directly boot with windows and i'm not asked if I want to boot with Ubuntu.

I've tried the following things:
- Boot-Repair gets an error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7772352/
- I can't disable Windows Secure Boot because the option doesn't appear in my BIOS menu. (I guess I just don't have Secure Boot)
- If I press F10 when the computer is booting, I get the following message: "Operative system not found"

At the moment I'm using a SuperGrub2 Disk CD to boot with Windows or Ubuntu but I wouldn't like to carry the CD everywhere to change between both operative systems.

I can't find other solutions that's why I asked here.

Comment: You can simply repair it with a SuperGrub2 CD. Source: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-super-grub2-disk/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

I've tried that but still doesn't work. I've followed the process and despite it is successfully done, I still boot with Windows 8.1 without being asked.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Where did you install grub?

Comment: Please provide details of your system. Make and model (assuming laptop based on your question)

Comment: I've installed grub in sda6, which is my "/" partition. After that, as it didn't work, I've installed it in every single partition but it still isn't working. My computer is a Sony Vaio SVS13A1S9ES

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/488500/can-i-install-ubuntu-14-04-on-sony-vaio-computers-with-uefi

Comment: I don't think so, Ubuntu seems to be well installed and the Live CD works.

Comment: I always install grub to the MBR of a hard disk rather than to a partition as I've found this to be more reliable. Perhaps you need a /boot partition with the approach you are taking. Or, perhaps more likely your Windows 8 is selected in the BIOS as the Primary boot.

Comment: How could I see if Windows is selected as the primary boot in the BIOS?

Comment: Please post a picture of your BIOS screen on imgur.com and provide the link in your question

Comment: Are you using UEFI or BIOS? No matter which you are using, you need to change nthe BIOS 9or UEFI) setting so that Ubuntu boots first.

Comment: Further research indicates that you may have installed a 32-bit version to an EFI BIOS System or Installed a 64-bit version in Legacy mode. Updated Answer

Comment: Did you already read http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported and try everything there. There is an order in which you need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**UEFI (~EFI)** is a firmware interface that is widespread on recent computers, especially those more recent than 2010. It is intended to replace the traditional BIOS firmware interface that is prevalent on earlier machines. This page provides information about installing and booting Ubuntu using EFI, as well as about switching between EFI mode and legacy BIOS mode using Ubuntu.

### Installing Ubuntu Quickly and Easily via Trial and Error

If you have a computer that is more recent than 2010 and you do not know whether or not you need to install Ubuntu in EFI mode, you should be able to get Ubuntu installed quickly and correctly using the following steps:

**Create a LiveDVD or LiveUSB of Ubuntu (>=12.04.2) 64bit.**

In your BIOS, disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT). If you have Windows8, also disable FastStartup.

Boot your PC using the LiveDVD or LiveUSB and choose "Try Ubuntu". If you get a Secure boot or signature error, you may wish to disable SecureBoot then retry to boot the disk.

Install Ubuntu from the Live CD/DVD or Live USB in the usual manner, then reboot the PC.

**If the PC does not load Ubuntu** (but instead loads Windows, for example, as in Bug #1050940), or if the Windows entry in the GRUB 2 menu does not boot Windows (see Bug #1024383), boot your PC using the Live CD/DVD or Live USB and choose "Try Ubuntu" once again. When the live session has loaded, run Boot-Repair (see link for details). When Boot-Repair loads, click on the "Recommended repair" button, and write on a paper the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXXX/) that will appear. Then reboot the pc. Do not run Boot-Repair unless you have problems booting the computer; the expression "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" applies to this tool.

This should fix most boot problems. If this does not fix your boot problems, please try to determine if you have accidentally installed a 32 bit version on a system that requires 64-bit EFI version or perhaps installed the right version in legacy mode. If you installed the right version in the wrong mode you can convert it (more on this later)

Installing Ubuntu in EFI mode

Warning: if you are a new Ubuntu user, you may want to follow the advice of the previous paragraph.

Case when Ubuntu must be installed in EFI mode

Having a PC with EFI firmware does not mean that you need to install Ubuntu in EFI mode. What is important is below:

If **the other systems (Windows Vista/7/8, GNU/Linux...) of your computer are installed in EFI mode**, then **you must install Ubuntu in EFI mode too.**

If the other systems (Windows, GNU/Linux...) of your computer are installed in Legacy (not-EFI) mode, then you must install Ubuntu in Legacy mode too. Eg if your computer is old (<2010), is 32bits, or was sold with a pre-installed Windows XP.

If Ubuntu is the only operating system on your computer, then it does not matter, you can install Ubuntu in EFI mode or not.

General principle

To install Ubuntu in EFI mode:

Use a 64bit disk of Ubuntu (Ubuntu32bit cannot be easily installed in UEFI mode)

Use a supported version of Ubuntu. Support for UEFI appeared in 11.10, but has become more reliable in next versions. Support for UEFI SecureBoot appeared in 12.10 and 12.04.2.

Set up your firmware (BIOS) to boot the disk in UEFI mode (see the "Identifying if the computer boots the HDD in EFI mode" paragraph below)

Then:
Nothing special is required if you use the automatic installer of Ubuntu ("Install Ubuntu alongside others" or "Erase the disk and install Ubuntu"). **Important: if you have a pre-installed Windows and you want to keep it, do not choose "Erase the disk and install Ubuntu".**

If you use the manual partitioning ("Something else"), the difference is that you will have to set the /boot/efi mount point to the EFI partition. And if there was not any EFI partition on your HDD, you first will have to create it (see the "Creating an EFI partition" paragraph below).

[image: img1]

Identifying if the computer boots the HDD in EFI mode

This is possible only if you have already installed Ubuntu on the HDD, or by looking at the BIOS setup (see paragraph below).

From an Ubuntu installed on the HDD (neither liveCD nor liveUSB), open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), then type the following command:

`[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"`

Remark: if the result is "Legacy boot on HDD", then either the BIOS is not UEFI type, or the BIOS is not set up to boot the HDD in UEFI mode.

### Identifying if the computer boots the Ubuntu DVD in EFI mode

Warning: even if your PC boots the DVD in EFI mode, it might boot the HDD in Legacy mode (and the contrary).

**When booting on a 64-bit Ubuntu disk:**

- If the BIOS is set up to boot the CD in EFI mode, then you will see the screen below:

[image: img2]

- If the BIOS is NOT set up to boot the CD in EFI mode, or if the disk is not 64-bit, then you will see the screen below:

[image: img3]

Set up the BIOS in EFI or Legacy mode

Some recent computers (>2011) allow to set up the boot either in UEFI mode or in Legacy (not-EFI) mode. The way to carry out this setting depends on the computers, but generally this setting is located in the "Boot order" tab of the BIOS (to access the BIOS screens, it is generally necessary to press a key during the PC startup).

Note: Some BIOSes (e.g. American Megatrends' "Aptio", found on the Asus vivobook series) call Legacy mode "Compatibility Support Module" or simply "CSM".

Remark: Some BIOSes allow one to set up the boot mode for the optical drive separately from the boot mode for the HDD.

For example, below:

The "UEFI Hitachi" line allows to boot the HDD in EFI mode,

The "P1: Hitachi" line allows to boot the HDD in Legacy (not-EFI) mode,

The "P3: DVD" line allows to boot the Ubuntu CD in Legacy mode

The "UEFI: USB" line allows to boot the Ubuntu liveUSB in EFI mode.

[image: img4]

Here is a 2nd example of BIOS, simpler, where the "Boot Mode" parameter allows one to choose the boot mode ("UEFI" or "Legacy") for all media (hard disk, CD, USB...) at the same time.

[image: img5]

Some other firmwares (BIOSes) propose an "UEFI/Legacy Boot:" option with the following choices: [Legacy only], [UEFI only] and [Both]. This last one boots in EFI mode when possible, then in Legacy mode if no EFI files are detected.

Creating an EFI partition

If you are manually partitioning your disk in the Ubuntu installer, you need to make sure you have an EFI partition set up.

If your disk already contains an EFI partition (eg if your computer had Windows8 preinstalled), it can be used for Ubuntu too. Do not format it. It is strongly recommended to have only 1 EFI partition per disk.

An EFI partition can be created via a recent version of GParted (the Gparted version included in the 12.04 disk is OK), and must have the following attributes:

Mount point: /boot/efi (remark: no need to set this mount point when using the manual partitioning, the Ubuntu installer will detect it automatically)

Size: minimum 100Mib. 200MiB recommended.

```
    Type: FAT32

    Other: needs a "boot" flag.
```

**Identifying if an Ubuntu has been installed in EFI mode**

An Ubuntu installed in EFI mode can be detected the following way:

```
its /etc/fstab file contains an EFI partition (mount point: /boot/efi)
it uses the grub-efi bootloader (not grub-pc)
from the installed Ubuntu, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) then type the following command:
```

`[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in EFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode"`

Converting Ubuntu into EFI or Legacy mode

**Converting Ubuntu into EFI mode**

Note: Do not follow this procedure if your computer is already booting correctly. **Use this procedure only if you believe you've accidentally installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode** and you want it to boot in EFI/UEFI mode.

Start Boot-Repair, click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab.
If you do not see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, this means that your PC does not have any EFI partition. In this case, exit Boot-Repair, then create an EFI partition (see the "Creating an EFI partition" paragraph above).
    If you see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, tick it then click the "Apply" button.

Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in EFI mode (see the ""Set up the BIOS in EFI or Legacy mode" paragraph above).

[image: img6]

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI